# Reading the data using raw_input()

Tags: python

[image]I have this code which work, I mean I got an output but then I got this error message 
"You must read the data using raw_input() and then convert it."

[image]

```
hrs = raw_input('Enter Hours:')
h = float(hrs)
if h >1.0 and h <= 40.0:
    pay = h*10
    print pay
elif h > 40: 
    pay = (40 * 10.50)+(((h-40)*10.50)*1.5)
 print pay
```

Did anybody know the reason?

Comment: Using Python 2.7.2 your code runs without problem. Unless you give it an empty answer, or something else that can not be converted to a number. Can you show us the python prompt after you run the code?

Comment: That is not a Python error message. *Where* are you getting that error?

Comment: You comment that this is from a learning platform, you should ask your learning platform supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, you are trying to pass tests in an automated testing system?
Maybe an online course? This might work.Also from seeing your image/question, you have missed the rate so it should look something like this:

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rate_hour = raw_input("Enter rate:")
r = float(rate_hour)
if h <= 40:
    print h * r
else :
    print (40 * r) + (h -40) * r * 1.5
```

Comment: Hmm strange.I am getting the correct answer. Inputting 45 hours and 10.50 as the rate per hour I get 498.75

Comment: Done!          in the question

Answer (score -1):

Hey Bro It will work fine in the Python 2.7 which version you are using.

Comment: This is not a solution, it should be a comment.